# JPA: Fetching list of entities by list of values for a given column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and Hibernate.

In one use case, I need to fetch all users from DB with associated email present in given email list.

To do this, I have written a custom JPA query as follows:

```
    @Query("SELECT u from User u where u.email in :emailIds")
    List<User> findUsersByEmailIds(@Param("emailIds") List<String> emailIdList);
```

But, I would like to know, is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: You will be able to avoid the `@Query` annotation if the method name is `List<User> findAllByEmailIn(List<String> emailIdList);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Vishnu, here is the explanation:

Assuming in your User entity you have a field like this:

```
private String email;
```

Then in your repository you can go like this:

```
List<User> findByEmailIn(List<String> emailIdList);
```

The important key thing to notice here is the `Capital E` in `findByEmailIn` while in your entity this field was `email` (small e). This way you can eliminate the `@Query` statement completely.